# Push model with new property to MongoDB

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I have a simple script that counts the number of documents of a particular user and assigns it to `externalUser.totalIcons` and after that saves this model to the database (MongoDB).

But when I'm trying to run it, it does not save the model and does not add a new property to the database.

Question: where I messed up something and what workaround can I apply here to see that script updated it in the database?

```
import { Icon, User } from '../../models'
import { runScript } from '../utils'

export async function run () {
  const userCriteria = { isExternal: true }
  const iconCriteria = { 'icons.source': 'external' }
  const externalUsers = await User.find(userCriteria)
  
for (const externalUser of externalUsers) {
    externalUser.totalIcons = await Icon.countDocuments({
      ...iconCriteria,
      'icons.userId': externalUser._id
    })
    console.log(externalUser._id + ' has: ' + externalUser.totalIcons)
    await externalUser.save()
  }
}

if (require.main === module) {
  runScript('totalIconsFieldUpdate', run)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: So the main problem was that I had models as microservices and I did not build it up to get a new field activated in `.js` file

Comment: Can you add the code you changed to the answer, so others in the future with the same problem will be able to understand the changes you made

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).